# If I delete every file, and then svn update, will I get the latest revision from the repo back?

Tags: svn

I have a lot of unneeded, uncommited files in the svn directory that I want gone. Do I just checkout at the root svn directory or do I have to delete everything first?

Thanks.

Comment: Can't you just use svn revert? In any case, your approach will also work.

Comment: Why don't you just try it out? It'll take less time than waiting for an answer.

Comment: I'm scared of breaking something.

Comment: That's what backups are for: breaking things in peace.

Comment: a "revert" wont change anything at the repository, but only your local copy.

Comment: Just make sure you don't delete the `.svn` directory. Revert won't remove untracked files. If you're really scared of losing something, rename away the old working dir and check out a fresh copy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you delete a file or directory and do an `svn update`, it will restore that file or directory to it's current pristine condition. I do this quite a bit when I decide all of the changes I did in a particular directory are garbage. Where this might cause problems (Might? Will cause problems!) is if you did an `svn move` from one directory you're not deleting to a directory you plan to delete. For example, I moved a file from the current directory to the `src` directory. Then, I make a whole slew of changes in the `src` directory. Deleting the `src` directory will not work in versions of Subversion before 1.7.

Truthfully, you're better off doing a `svn revert` (you can use the `--recursive` switch to go deep into your directories so a `svn --recursive *` will do everything). Then try a `svn status` to see if there are any files that are still not in sorts. If you have conflicts, doing a `svn resolved` on that file or directory, then doing a `svn revert` should help clean that up if a regular `svn revert` doesn't do it.

My suggestion is to depend upon `svn status` to tell you what changes there are. If you have anything that is showing up in an `svn status` revert it, resolve it, updated it, until it's gone.

If you are really deleting everything in your working directory, just delete the whole directory and do a new checkout. That way, you don't get into issues where you mess up the `.svn` directory/directories.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you keep what is inside the .svn directory(/directories if you use Subversion <= 1.6), the only thing you might lose is your local changes, which is exactly what you wanted anyway.

Deleting the local files, followed by an update will first reinstall the files (as unmodified) and then perform the update. This reinstall is mostly equivalent to just `svn revert`-ing the files.

So which way you choose is not really relevant as it only differs a bit in the amount of IO performed, except when you also have local svn property changes (or local copies and deletes). In this case you really need to svn revert your working copy.

In any case I would recommend running a `svn status` when you are done, as that will show you if you still have local changes left that need more work.